# C# - Using TCP client trough PROXY

Tags: c#, .net, networking, proxy, tcpclient

We have 2 software's (Server and client) that communicate using TCP client.
One of our customers is working trough proxy and therefore can't use our client.

Is there a way to open a TCP client trough proxy in C#?

Please note, HTTP proxy is not good enough since our server is not working in that mode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of proxy? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289418/c-sharp-tcpclient-connect-via-a-proxy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751835/connecting-to-a-tcp-server-via-tcpclient-through-proxy

Comment: "...and therefore can't use our client" -- please be more specific. Many proxies are configured to pass client traffic through unscathed. The vast majority of the remained _can_ be so configured, but aren't for some reason. Some times this is a perceived security issue for IT, other times it's just an oversight. But since normally a TCP client behind a proxy can access a server, you'll need to explain why it is that a) your customer can't, and b) this is a _programming_ question rather than a network configuration question.